# SQL Insert row when a cell does not contain a specific set of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My database has a column named `Group`.

This `Group` can be one of two values:

1. `Group101`   = Main group
2. `Group101D1` = Subgroup

Every group has two options like this.

[image]

But I have some situations where `Group101D1` exists but `Group101` does not.

Now I want to create an insert where I search for groups with `D1` that doesn't have a main group. for example I have `Group105D1` but don't have Group105. I want an insert to create a row with `Group105`.

This is as far as I have come:

```
INSERT INTO (Group)
    SELECT [Table1].[Group], [Table2].[Group]
    FROM [Table] Table1
    INNER JOIN [Table] Table2 ON [table1].[Group] = [Table2].[Group]
    -- WHERE [Table2].[Group] LIKE '%D1'
    --   AND [Table1].[Group] NOT LIKE '%D1'
```

Can some of you please help, I don't know how to finish this.

I know I probably need to use inner join, replace and a where not clause.

Comment: Please add few rows of sample data and expected output. What RDBMS you are using

Comment: I am using Microsoft sql server management 2017 and will make a small image of my database and add it to my question!

Comment: Most people here prefer as formatted text than images

Comment: Do u have these in 2 tables or just in one table with 2 columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need `replace` Also query should exclude rows already exists

Sample data:

```
 DECLARE @groups TABLE ([Group] VARCHAR(100), description VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @groups ([Group], description)
SELECT 'Group101', 'Something1'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Group101d1', 'Something1'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Group105d1', 'description_Bleh'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Group2054', 'desc_2054'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Group2054d1', 'desc_2054'
```

Use replace function and exclude Maingroup if it exists

```
SELECT Replace([group], 'd1', '') [Group], description
FROM @groups
WHERE [Group] NOT IN (
        SELECT p.[Group]
        FROM @groups g
        INNER JOIN @groups p
            ON g.[Group] = replace(p.[Group], 'd1', '')
        )
```

Result:

```
Group         description
Group105    description_Bleh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and `REPLACE` to get the desired results like below :

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Group)
 select  replace([Group], 'd1', '') from Table1 a
 where [Group] like '%d1' and 
 not exists(
     select 1 from Table1 where [group] = replace(a.[Group], 'd1', '')
     )
```

Comment: Look at that select again

Answer (score 0):

If all subgroups ends with "D1" you can use below query to insert missing main groups.

```
INSERT INTO (Group)
SELECT
left(subtable.Group,(len(subtable.Group)-len('D1')))
FROM
[Table1].[Group] subtable
where 
charindex (  'D1', subtable.Group) > 0 -- if it is sub-record
and
 not exists --check if main group exists
  (SELECT
1
FROM
[Table1].[Group] main
where (charindex (    main.Group+'D1', subtable.Group) != 0)   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stuff you have already just packaged with data

```
DECLARE @groups TABLE (grp VARCHAR(100), description VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @groups (grp, description) values 
         ('Group101', 'Something1')
       , ('Group101d1', 'Something1')
       , ('Group105d1', 'description_Bleh')
       , ('Group106d1', 'description_Bleh6')
       , ('Group2054', 'desc_2054')
       , ('Group2054d1', 'desc_2054');
select * from @groups order by grp; 
insert into @groups
select replace(g1.grp, 'd1', ''), g1.description 
  from @groups g1
 where g1.grp like '%d1' 
   and not exists ( select 1 
                    from @groups g2 
                    where g2.Grp = replace(g1.grp, 'd1', '') 
                  );
select * from @groups order by grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way in the end!

```
insert into Table (Group, Description)
select  replace(Group,'D1','') , description from Table
where Group like '%D1'
and replace(Group,'D1','') not in (
select Group from Table
where Group like 'Group%' and Group not like '%D1')
```